# why getting the focus trigs databinding in angular 5?

Tags: data-binding, angular5, angular2-changedetection

Developing a multiculture Angular5 app I've structured a class which contains a dictionary (custom ts class) to hold the translations. When the user changes the culture, anything related to it must change. **It works but.... too much**.

Since I use to console.log everytime the method which gets the right sentence according to the selected culture is called, I noticied that if I just click on a textbox, Angular updates everything and, incomprehensibly, if I click on nothing soon after just to leave the focus, again angular updates everything! I know there must be something related with ChangeDetectionStrategy but I tried to solve without any success.

When the app grows up, if the browser has to reload everything everytime... what a problem! The app looks like this:

a MainController.ts holds anything can be useful to the components so it is passed in every component constructor.

MainController looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class MainController extends BaseClass {
    private currentCulture: string;
    private platformLocalizedSentencies: KeyedCollection<LocalizedString>;
```

the class LocalizedString looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class LocalizedString extends BaseClass {
    public DefaultText: string;
    public IdTranslationIndex: number;
    public Translations: KeyedCollection<string>;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.Translations = new KeyedCollection<string>();
    }

    public GetTranslation(culture: string) {
        console.log('getting translation for ' + this.DefaultText + ' in culture ' + culture);

        if (!this.Translations.ContainsKey(culture)) {
            return '*' + this.DefaultText;
        } else {
            return this.Translations.Item(culture);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, there's a component (culture-selector.component.ts) which shows flags (changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush) and when the user select a flag this happens:

```
onCultureClick(menuItem: string) {
    console.log(menuItem + ' clicked.');
    this.mainController.CurrentCulture = menuItem; // this must be the thing which unleash the databinding on the other components I think and I hope
    this.updateSelectedCultureUI(); // doesn't do anything special, just sets the right flag and culture name on the top of the control
    this.mainController.trace(TraceType.Info, 'Culture ' + this.cultureName + ' clicked');
  }
```

and the component where I noticied the hell wild by the databinding, the login component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
})

export class LoginComponent extends BaseClass implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
constructor(public mainController: MainController) { 
    super();
  }

ngOnInit() {
    this.usernamePlaceholder = this.mainController.PlatformLocalizedSentencies.Item('Username');
```

Now, "usernamePlaceholder" is used into the html like this:

```
<mat-form-field style="width: 100%;">
            <input matInput [placeholder]="usernamePlaceholder.GetTranslation(mainController.CurrentCulture)" [(ngModel)]="loginInput.username" (keypress)="eventHandler($event.keyCode, 'txtUsername')" #txtUsername>
</mat-form-field>
```

in the following picture you can see into the console-window what happens if I just click into the username textbox.... I cleared the console before clicking. What is going on? I spent two days trying to undestand... sorry it's my first angular App.. I should have started with something easier :)

You can see username translation is get by ClassLibray.ts while the other sentencies by mainController.ts... this is because I tried different ways but same result... in mainController the code is almost the same:

.... and the method to retrieve the correct string

```
 public GetPlatformSentence(key: string) {
        console.log('getting translation for ' + key + ' in culture ' + this.CurrentCulture);

        if (!this.PlatformLocalizedSentencies.ContainsKey(key)) {
            return '[NOTRANSLATION]';
        }
        if (!this.PlatformLocalizedSentencies.Item(key).Translations.ContainsKey(this.CurrentCulture)) {
            return '*' + this.PlatformLocalizedSentencies.Item(key).DefaultText;
        } else {
            return this.PlatformLocalizedSentencies.Item(key).Translations.Item(this.CurrentCulture);
    }

}
```

Thank you anyway

[here is what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYTmx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I've tried anything without any success. Angular binding is... too pedantic :-)
The best result I was able to achieve was the refresh at first user-interaction. So I had to choose between refreshing everything everytime (which was too much) or refreshing as soon as the user clicked somewhere forcing the binding refresh (that was what I've been able to get playing with ChangeDetectionStrategy settings and some additional code).

So I solved (just for multicuture immediate binding) using a messageService. Every component subscribes and asks to a common maicontroller to update anything related on culture when it changes. Of course I needed to write e little bit more code but the result in terms of user experience, responsiveness and CPU load is very very nice. Also the executed code is the same for every component so it is not so bad.

Of course it isn't what I expected but, it works better for me.